# How get hyperref to make entire index entry a link?

Tags: hyperref, indexing

With `hyperref` option `hyperindex` I get links on the page numbers of entries in the Index.

Is there an option to `hyperref`, or an additional package, that makes the entire index entry — term and page number — into a clickable link?

Comment: No, links can only jump to *one* location. It is common that index terms can have more than one page.

Comment: OK, that's a clear and totally reasonable answer! Thanks.

Comment: Since the comment seems to have answered the question already, I converted the comment to an official answer (to push the question off the unanswered question list).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `hyperref` does not have an option to make index terms to links. A link can only have *one* target. But it is quite common that index terms can have more than one page.